# Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements. Reduce the number or size of the prepared statements

Tags: azure-sql-database, oracle-data-integrator, azure-synapse

I am trying to insert record in to Azure sql Dataware House using Oracle ODI, but i am getting error after insertion of some records.

NOTE: I am trying to insert 1000 records, but error is coming after 800.

Error Message: Caused By: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: 112007;Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements. Reduce the number or size of the prepared statements.

I am trying to insert 1000 records,but error is coming after 800.

Error Message: Caused By: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: 112007;Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements. Reduce the number or size of the prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

While Abhijith's answer is technically correct, I'd like to suggest an alternative that will give you far better performance.

The root of your problem is that you've chosen the worst-possible way to load a large volume of data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse. A long list of INSERT statements is going to perform very badly, no matter how many DWUs you throw at it, because it is always going to be a single-node operation.

My recommendation is to adapt your ODI process in the following way, assuming that your Oracle is on-premise.

- Write your extract to a file
- Invoke AZCOPY to move the file to Azure blob storage
- CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE to map a view over the file in storage
- CREATE TABLE AS or INSERT INTO to read from that view into your target table

This will be orders of magnitude faster than your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

20MB is the limit defined and it is hard limit for now. Reducing the batch size will certainly help you work around this limit.

Link to capacity limits.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-service-capacity-limits

Comment: Actually error is coming on Oracle Odi side. And i have all ready scale up Azure dataware house to G2 - 1000c.

Comment: 1000 row is not more , I think 20 MB memory limit is sufficient for inserting these records.