# pandas to_sql() error - Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements

Tags: python, sql, pandas, azure

I'm already using a chunksize of 50 and im running into memory errors. I need to upload about 250M records in total so if I use any lower of a chunksize I dont think it will finish within the next decade. Any tips on how to get around this?

Database = Azure SQL Server

```
final_df.to_sql('table', con=engine, schema='example', index=False, chunksize=50, if_exists='append', dtype={'ID':sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255),'MSA_NAME':sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
```

Comment: can you add in your odbc statement? might be easier to use bulk insert with powershell especially since you need to insert 250m records. what's the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using  `fast_executemany=True` and `method='multi'` -

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params, echo=False, connect_args={'autocommit': True}, fast_executemany=True)
```

...

```
final_df.to_sql('table', con=engine, schema='example', index=False, method='multi',  if_exists='append', dtype={'ID':sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255),'MSA_NAME':sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest an alternative.

You could export the data as CSV  and have it uploaded to one of Azure Storage Services ( Blob for instance - You could probably use AZCopy to achieve.

Then use Azure Data Factory in order to copy/import the files to the Azure SQL.

[Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

You could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56767006/exceeded-the-memory-limit-of-20-mb-per-session-for-prepared-statements-reduce-t) which has a similar discussion.